# Problems storing strings with scanf

Tags: c, gcc, scanf, cc

I'm having problems with `scanf` in C. After reading other Stackoverflow posts on how to fix problems with `scanf`, I now know that `scanf` is not recommended, but I have to use it for a homework assignment. I am trying to store 3 string values that have a maximum size according to their buffer size. When I compile and run this program, I input the values `255 255 255` and this is what is printed.

```
1:
2:
3: 255
```

Here is the program source:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(){
     char first[8] = "", second[3] = "", third[3] = "";
     scanf("%8s %3s %3s", first, second, third);
     printf("1: %s\n2: %s\n3: %s", first, second, third);
}
```

Comment: Do you know how strings are represented in C?

Comment: `char first[9] = "", second[4] = "", third[4] = "";`

Comment: @EugeneSh. Yes, as an array of characters.

Comment: **null terminated** array of chars

Comment: @T94j0 Just that? What about null-termination?

Comment: @LPs I got it. I totally forgot about the \0. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As currently defined, the arrays can only store very short strings:

- `char first[8]` can only store 7 bytes and a null terminator,
- `char second[3]` can only store 2 bytes and a null terminator,
- `char third[3]` can only store 2 bytes and a null terminator.

The `scanf` format string should be:

```
scanf("%7s %2s %2s", first, second, third);
```

The current code invokes undefined behavior as you store strings longer than the array sizes for `second` and `third`.

To parse longer strings, you should define the arrays as

```
char first[9] = "", second[4] = "", third[4] = "";
```

And you should check the return value of `scanf()`.